# Where and how to assign a user :admin role for attr_accessible in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In Rails guide in http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html, section 6.1, it introduces a role for attr_accessible with :as option,

```
attr_accessible :name, :is_admin, :as => :admin
```

My question is, if a user log in, where and how can I assign the user to :admin role so she/he gets the right to mass assign with attr_accessible? Also can I define my own role such as group_to_update? If it does, what should go into the definition of group_to_update?

Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are using some technical terminology in vague ways that is making your understanding of this process muddled, so I'm going to clear up this terminology first.

> where and how can I assign the user to :admin role

The 'role' used in the `:as` parameter to `attr_accessible` is not a user role. It is an *attribute* role. It means that attribute is protected from overwriting unless that role is specified in the statement that sets the attribute. So, this system is independent of any user system. Your application doesn't even need to have users to have roles in mass assignment.

> can I define my own role such as group_to_update

Roles are not really "defined" in any formal sense at all. In any place that a role is expected, simply use any symbol/string (e.g. `:group_to_update`) as the role. No need to specify it anywhere else ahead of time.

Here's how it works. Normally, during mass assignment of a hash to model attributes, all of the model's attributes are used as keys to the assigned hash. So if you have a `Barn` model and `barn` instance of it, with three attributes `horse`, `cat`, and `rabbit`, then this:

```
barn.attributes = params
```

Is essentially the same as doing:

```
barn.horse = params[:horse]
barn.cat = params[:cat]
barn.rabbit = params[:rabbit]
```

Now, if you set any `attr_accessible` on the barn model, only the attributes you set there will be updated when you use mass assignment. Example:

```
class Barn < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :cat
    attr_accessible :rabbit
end
```

Then this:

```
barn.attributes = params
```

Will only do this:

```
barn.cat = params[:cat]
barn.rabbit = params[:rabbit]
```

Because only 'cat' and 'rabbit' are set to accessible ('horse' is not). Now consider setting an attribute role like this:

```
class Barn < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :cat
    attr_accessible :rabbit, :as => :banana
end
```

First, note that the the role can by *anything you want* as long as it is a symbol/string. In this case, I made the role `:banana`. Now, when you set a role on an `attr_accessible` attribute, it normally does not got assigned. This:

```
barn.attributes = params
```

Will now only do this:

```
barn.cat = params[:cat]
```

But you can assign attributes *using a specific role* by using the `assign_attributes` method. So you can do:

```
barn.assign_attributes(params, :as => :banana)
```

This will assign all normally-protected params as well as all params protected under the role `:banana`:

```
barn.cat = params[:cat]
barn.rabbit = params[:rabbit]
```

So consider a longer example with more attributes:

```
class Barn < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :cat
    attr_accessible :rabbit, :as => :banana
    attr_accessible :horse, :as => :banana
    attr_accessible :cow, :as => :happiness
end
```

Then you can use those roles when assigning attributes. This:

```
barn.assign_attributes(params, :as => :banana)
```

Corresponds to:

```
barn.cat = params[:cat]
barn.rabbit = params[:rabbit]
barn.horse = params[:horse]
```

And this:

```
barn.assign_attributes(params, :as => :happiness)
```

Corresponds to:

```
barn.cat = params[:cat]
barn.cow = params[:cow]
```

Now, *if you choose to*, you can make user roles (e.g. a "role" column on your User model) correspond to attribute roles on any model. So you could do something like this:

```
barn.assign_attributes(params, :as => user.role)
```

If this `user`'s role happens to be `banana`, then (using our last model example) it will set attributes on barn for cat, rabbit, and horse. But this is just one way to use attribute roles. It is entirely up to you if you want to use them a different way.

Comment: Thank you. It is probably the only post going into the great detail about role in attr_accessible. One more question, how the role is going to prevent the mass assignment from happening? Is there no way for a hacker to include the role in the URL?

Comment: Excellent answer. This should be somewhere [in the guides?] in the Rails docs.

Comment: @user938363, that's up to you. The role is only set when you use `:as => whatever_role`. It's your responsibility to make sure nothing from the url get used directly in the spot for the role there. Really though, this isn't a big responsibility; you'd have to try to make it happen that way on purpose for it to be at all vulnerable. The attribute role system doesn't even have to be used in a web application at all (see for yourself -- it will work from the rails console command line).

Comment: One more question, is there a way role can be used to control how a login user can edit or create new record?

Comment: @user938363, I don't really understand what your question means. It sounds like you are starting to talk about a user role system, which works in a completely different way than the attribute role system.

Comment: my understanding about :as role is that the role provides security from malicious mass assignment by including :as option in attr_accessible. Is it true?

Comment: I have been puzzling about :as option in attr_accessible. My understanding was that the :as option is like a safe guard to model data and could be defined in app. I guess it is not the case after reading your post. Then what's the purpose of :as option in attr_accessbile?

Comment: It does safegaurd model data. It will only let attributes be assigned if the corresponding role is set. So in the final example from this post, if a form submitted and populated a params hash with `{:cat => 'asdf', :rabbit => 'qwerty'}`, by default, doing `barn.attributes = params` will only set `barn.cat` because `barn.rabbit` is only accessible with `:as` set to `banana`.

Comment: If you had a logged in user whole `user.role == 'banana'` and you did `barn.assign_attributes(params, user.role)` this would expand to `barn.assign_attributes(params, 'banana')` -- and in this case both `barn.cat` and `barn.rabbit` will be set.

Comment: So :as option allows the mass assignment happening only if the pre-coded :as role is met and a hacker can not set the :as role online (assignment protection is provided), right?

Comment: Thank you. I wish rails user guide will have great details as it is in your post and discussions thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

This is to protect against mass assignment as your link explains.

In rails (for updating) this only affects the [update_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/update_attributes) call.  You can still use [update_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/update_attribute) or admin= methods to assign the admin variable.

```
User.first.update_attributes(:name => "Gazler", :admin => true) #this will not work
User.first.update_attribute(:admin, true) #This will work

#This will also work
user = User.first
user.admin = true
user.save
```

You might want to take a look at using a [gem for your permissions](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=permissions).  [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) is probably the most common.

Comment: Here you used the individual assignment which should work all the time. But who could be admin role and how to become an admin role? I assume admin is a method which could be defined.

Comment: No, admin in this case would be a property on your User model.  You can assign this in the rails console or through a form like any other property.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [assign_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/assign_attributes) method.

In short, it enables you to asign the attributes only when you also pass the role. The docs have very nice and easily understandable code examples. In a way, it works like kind of a filter, or guard.